# Book where a professor of language dying of cancer is reincarnated in to the body of a cat/man hybrid

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I am looking for the title of a book in which the main character is a professor who dying of cancer.  He is on a cruise and traveling when killed by a meteor.  He is then reincarnated into the body of a cat-like human.  It turns out that the planet is earth thousands of years in the past.

Comment: If you are reborn back in a time before your previous life, would that be "preincarnation?"

Answer (score 1):

As per [A book where a man inhabits the body of a dying man and befriends a telepathic cat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167902/a-book-where-a-man-inhabits-the-body-of-a-dying-man-and-befriends-a-telepathic-c), this is likely the *[Gandalara Cycle](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/973586)* by Randall Garrett and Vicki Ann Heydron.

> When the fireball hit the cruise ship, Richard Carillo was already on his way out - a terminally ill language professor. He regained consciousness as a well man in the desert... only it wasn't a desert on Earth, and he was a man only because he was still male. More surpises awaited him in the exotic city of Raithskar - he was called Markasset, a master swordsman, son of a powerful leader, and a man on the run, accused of murder and the theft of a precious, sacred jewel. With the aid of Keeshah, a great war-cat with which he shared a telepathic link, he set out to clear his newfound name...

I asked about it myself [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78882/book-about-a-man-transported-to-a-desert-world-buildings-are-made-from-salt-and).